# Initialise a vue.js 3 project with webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nodes

One used to be able to initialise a vue.js 2 project with webpack using "vue init webpack client". In vue.js 3 project, from my understanding, one needs to use "vue create" to create a new project. However, this does not initialise the project with webpack. I am not finding any example of a command replacing the one used in vue.js 2, which could be used to initialise a vue.js 3 project, but only manual steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vue create` scaffolds a Vue project that uses Webpack under the hood. Webpack is a build dependency of `@vue/cli-service`. You'll see it listed when running `npm list webpack` from the root of your scaffolded project:

```
$ npm list webpack
vue3-proj@0.1.0 /Users/tony/src/tmp/vue3-proj
├─┬ @vue/cli-plugin-babel@4.5.12
│ ├─┬ babel-loader@8.2.2
│ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ cache-loader@4.1.0
│ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ thread-loader@2.1.3
│ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ └─┬ webpack@4.46.0
│   └─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@1.4.5
│     └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
├─┬ @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.5.12
│ ├─┬ eslint-loader@2.2.1
│ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
└─┬ @vue/cli-service@4.5.12
  ├─┬ @intervolga/optimize-cssnano-plugin@1.0.6
  │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
  ├─┬ @soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin@1.8.0
  │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
  ├─┬ @vue/preload-webpack-plugin@1.1.2
  │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
  ├─┬ copy-webpack-plugin@5.1.2
  │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
  ├─┬ css-loader@3.6.0
  │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
  ├─┬ file-loader@4.3.0
  │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
  ├─┬ html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0
  │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
  ├─┬ mini-css-extract-plugin@0.9.0
  │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
  ├─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@2.3.8
  │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
  ├─┬ url-loader@2.3.0
  │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
  ├─┬ vue-loader@15.9.6
  │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
  ├─┬ webpack-dev-server@3.11.2
  │ ├─┬ webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.3
  │ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
  │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
  └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
```